# Uncaught TypeError:.get$price is not a function

Tags: dart

I am trying to use fold method to sum up values from instance field of objects. runtimeType looks ok, but cannot figure out what the problem is.

> Uncaught TypeError: prev.get$price is not a function

thanks.

```
void main() {
  int sum(int x,int y){return x+y;};
  
  var total=products.fold(0,(prev,next)=>sum(prev.price,next.price));
  print(total);
  
  products.forEach((item)=>print(item.price.runtimeType));
 
}


List<Product> products = [
  Product(name:'car',price:18),
  Product(name:'toy',price:22),
  Product(name:'box',price:24),
 ];

class Product{
  String name;
  int price;
  Product({this.name,this.price});
 }
```

Comment: There is no prev.get$price being written in this code. Are you running the code through some builder? If so, did you include the proper part/import steps given in the directions? It might also help to push out your "pubspec.yaml" file here.

Comment: Does the below answer solve your issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, your syntax is incorrect. Here is a correct syntax for `fold` method

```
var total = products.fold(0, (prevValue, element) => sum(prevValue, element.getPrice()));
```

Comment: Thanks, of course, you are right. I am trying to get a price out of an integer by saying "prev.price" :)